# how to insert a value of each iterations dynamically in the id's using jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, xslt

I need to insert value of each iteration in id="funDirName" and id="addr1" and i have added the below code block for reference:
<!--
Expected Result:

```
<p id="funDirName">Floyd and Son (Funeral Directors) Ltd</p>
<p id="addr1">Aaron House</p>

<p id="funDirName">Lincolnshire Co-operative Funeral Service</p>
<p id="addr1">Duke Street</p> 
-->
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     var types = [];
     var address1 = [];
     var otherTypes = [];
     $("input[id*='street_address_']").each(function(index) {
         otherTypes.push($(this).val());
         address1 = otherTypes[index].split(',');
         var obj = {};
         obj.funName = address1[0];
         obj.addr1 = address1[1];
         types.push(obj);
           
         console.log("address1");
         console.log(address1);
         console.log(types); 
         var funDirName = types[index].funName;
            
         $('#funDirName').text(funDirName);
            
         $('#addr1').text(address1[1]);
            
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<p id = "funDirName" style = "margin: 0;" ></p>           
<p id = "addr1" style = "margin: 0;" ></p>
```

Comment: I believe `address1[index].funName;` should be `types[index].funName;` but please include the `street_address_` inputs and what is the expected result

Comment: IDs should be unique, you shouldn't use the same `id=addr1` in multiple elements.

Comment: can you please give me an example